# How to reverse the print out of numbers

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to learn C# for my university degree and I can't work out how to get my code to print out only the even numbers from 0-100 starting at the largest number i.e 100 down too 0. I have the code printing the output from smallest to largest but cannot get it to go the other way around.

Can anyone give me a hand?

This is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Print first 100 even No in reverse");

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: `for( int i = 100; i > 0; i-- )`  That's all you need I think.

Comment: Fantastic thank you

Comment: you should include 0 if it's supposed to print out 0. The modulo check can be removed if you use i-=2 instead of i--.

Comment: `Console.Write(string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Reverse()));`

Comment: Range(1, 100).Reverse()

Answer (score 0):

you just need to start your loop from 100 and decrease from there:

```
 for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
```

use `">"` instead of `">="` operator, if you don't want the zero included

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your code with this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Print first 100 even No in reverse");

for (int i = 100; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
    }
}
```